# How to set isLogged variable for other components in angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

I have  a principalService for get current authenticated user from back server , and authService.ts contains a local variable 'isLogged:boolean' .

**target**: want to get the value of  'isLogged' from authService in NavbarComponent .

**principalService:**

```
currentUser():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("auth-server/uaa/user")
      .map((res:Response)=> res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

**authService:**

```
isLogged:boolean=false;

  constructor(private principal:PrincipalService) {
    this.authenticated();
  }

  authenticated() {
    this.principal.currentUser().subscribe(e=> {
        if (e) {
          console.log('user has logged in');
          this.isLogged = true;
        }
      },
      error=> {
        this.isLogged = false;
      }
    )
  }
```

**and NavbarComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('auth service isLogged is : '+this.authService.isLogged);
  }
```

**what and how i use value of 'isLogged' from authService is  :**

when logout -- I want to change the

> isLogged status of authService

and

> whether to display the 'login' and 'logout' button depends on isLogged
>   status of authService

**the problems is :**

when logged in ,i hope

> 'this.authService.isLogged value is true  in NavbarComponent '

,but i do not , How resolve .

Answer (score 0):

This `authService.isLogged` is `true` when the response from the HTTP request arrives. Angular doesn't wait for the response, but instead continues executing code. The call to `auth-server/uaa/user` is only scheduled (added to the event queue) and processed async. When then later the response arrives, the callback you passed to `.subscribe(...)` is called.

There is no guarantee at all that the response has been arrived in `ngOnInit()`.

What you can do depends on where or how you use the `isLogged` value.

Comment: In NavbarComponent , **when logout , I want to change the` isLogged status of authService`** , and **whether to display the 'login' and 'logout' button depends on `isLogged status of authService`**

Comment: The async behavior explained above shouldn't prevent you doing that. Do you get any error? What is you code/HTML where that causes you troubles?

Comment: the problem is when login in ,the value **isLogged** is still false in NavbarComponent

Comment: HTTP requests are quite slow compared to code executed within the browser but user action (like a click) usually are even slower by far, therefore it is unlikely that the response takes so long, especially if you are using a local development server (which doesn't need to communicate over slow internet connection). Maybe you are providing `PrincipalService` more than once in your application and there are different instances, but if you fetch login status from the constructor of the service each service instance should have the correct status.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell from the information you provided what might cause the problems. Can you provide more information (code) for me to see what's going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115790/discussion-between-kery-hu-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave. Just edit your question and add the code there.